# How to create polygon "stamps"  and extend lines by fixed distance? in QGIS

Tags: qgis, cartography, cad

This is related to [Does QGIS have these CAD editing functions?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27157/does-qgis-have-these-cad-editing-functions)

Cadtools have solved a lot of the issues I had but I need the ability to see how long a line is while I am drawing an orthoganal polygon? Is there a way to do this? can we change the Coordinate output on the bottom toolbar to show meters from last vertex rather than the coordinate or like in ESRI set an extend by X meters at Y angle?

Also can I pre-create a block of say 3m x 1.5m and then drop paste it in into a shape file? Obviously I can copy paste but can you create a stamp so that it fits into angular lines as well...

The current usage is I am trying to create a qgis based system where non-GIS people can create market stalls within a building easily.